# Is it okay that I taped over ventilation outlets?

Tags: ventilation, tape

I live in a building where I have no control over ventilation, it is very loud and annoying, the smell from othe people rooms and cooking is coming inside my room, together with the awful amount of dust. I taped over both ventilation outlets, the one that sucks the air from the room and the one that puts air inside the room. Is this okay for the ventilation system, that is apparently connected for all the units in the building?

Answer (score 3):

> the smell from other people rooms and cooking is coming inside my room

And any airborne viruses...

The ventilation system isn't supposed to suck air from other people's appartments and blow it into yours. If it does, then something is absolutely wrong with the system. Maybe the fan that's supposed to suck outside air and blow it in is out of order.

If it smells like cooking, then maybe someone in the building plugged the outlet of their kitchen hood into the wrong pipe, so instead of going outside, it goes to everyone else's appartments.

You can try talking with whoever manages the building.

But taping over the vents won't break anything. Just remember to open the windows once in a while, especially if you air dry some clothes, otherwise without ventilation it'll get damp and moldy.

Comment: Most residential hvac systems have return air and don't use fresh air.  I imagine a lot of older buildings do the same thing where they don't have a heat exchanger - some of the return air would be sucked out of the building as combustion air at the return point assuming the hvac is using combustion.

Comment: It is actually a completely new building, but it's a student residence and I guess they were going for the cheapest option possible, especially because I have no control over switching it on/off. I do open windows and doors very often. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

This happens a lot in older building that utilize ductless vent, relying on the space between joists to vent air. Taping them up will not cause any damage to the system.

You might want to think about getting a window fan, window AC or portable AC unit. Running these would give you a pressure increase that could cancel the air flowing into your unit from these vent if you untaped them. If you kept them taped up, you'd get some fresh, filtered air (with the AC units) and just fresh air with the fan.

Comment: My only concern was not to cause damage, otherwise I am completely fine without it and I open my windows often ane air is always fresh. Thank you for your answer!